# Where can you find the Yeti Zombie?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies

I know that the Yeti Zombie is a zombie that you have to "discover", but I never saw him once in a whole first adventure! I was wondering if there are any tips or techniques for catching ( well, finding ) the Yeti Zombie. I'm in suspense and I really want to know what he looks like, and what he does. It would be a great help. Thanks!